# Python datetime.strptime Default

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way to get `datetime.strptime()` to give me a default value on a failed parse (`None` in this case)? I have user entered data from a file that could be improperly formatted dates. The dates should be in the form mm/dd/yy, but some people have put them dd/mm/yy. So the file could look like this:

```
user1 01/30/14
user2 02/19/12
user3 27/02/11
```

I don't need to account for the improperly formatted dates, so I can just return `None`. I know I can do this with:

```
try:
    return datetime.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%y')
except:
    return None
```

But I'd like to have something a little more gracefully. Is anyone aware of a solution here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current solution seems very elegant.  Although I would catch the specific exception that `strptime` raises instead of a bare `except:` (catches everything).

Comment: Your bigger problem here is that mixing those two date formats leads to ambiguity - what should `10/11/12` be parsed to?

Comment: It's such a shame this can't be done within a lambda :\

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` package does not offer a built-in solution to your problem.

A more graceful (close to your suggestion) solution would be to define your own function (for instance, in your utils.py file or equivalent).

```py
from datetime import datetime

def strptime(date_string, format, default=None):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default
```

The following exception will be raised (you  might want to handle other exceptions):

- TypeError: In case `date_string` is not a `str` (e.g. if you pass None)
- ValueError: In case `date_string` mismatch the format

You could then import your `strptime` (from your `utils` for instance) instead of `datetime.datetime.strptime`.